# How to get the DataSource name in dropdownlist control in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, connection-string

Hi I am developing an application to retrieve data from one system to another remote system.

To do this I am firstly setting the connection string of the application by below screen.

[image: Control panel]

When I chose the SQL Server from first `dropdownlist` I need that the available `DataSource name` or `database instance name` like `sa` or anything by witch the database installed, should be come in second `dropdownlist` and again when I select `DataSource available`, `database name` should be prompt in 3rd `dropdownlist`.

I don't have any idea about this how can I do this. Currently I am doing this manually but it's time consuming and error prone.

How can we resolve it and also for MySql too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the database instance name using following code

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            cboServerName.Items.Add(row["ServerName"]);
        }
```

and for the databases in that server you can use this code

```
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("server=" + cboServerName.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";uid=" + txtUsername.Text + ";pwd=" + txtPassword.Text);
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            //if connection was successful,fetch the list of databases available in that server
            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCom.Connection = SqlCon;
            SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCom.CommandText = "sp_databases";        //sp_databases procedure used to fetch list of available databases

            SqlDataReader SqlDR;
            SqlDR = SqlCom.ExecuteReader();

            while (SqlDR.Read())
            {
                cboDatabase.Items.Add(SqlDR.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed...Please check username and password","Error");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution..It's perfect.. Do you have any idea about how can we do this on MySQL..??